# What does it mean by to 'hit an air pocket'?

Tags: phrases, idioms

What does it mean by the phrase 'hitting an air pocket'?

Does this mean 'to attain such a situation where someone/something can no longer advance forward'?

If that is correct, then, what is the origin of this phrase?

Comment: It's a term from aviation.  Did you try Googling it??

Comment: You are supposed to do your own research.  If you Google `"hitting an air pocket"` (with the quotes) you will have your answer.

Comment: I googled air pocket, meaning and got many hits.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it needs more context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The literal meaning of "air pocket" is "a nearly vertical air current that can cause an aircraft to experience a sudden change in altitude, usually a decrease" ([Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/air-pocket)). It's basically a synonym for **turbulence**--when your smooth airplane ride suddenly becomes a lot bumpier.

It's from this literal meaning that the figurative meaning has arisen: You  might say that a plan *hit an air pocket* when it ran into unexpected difficulties. In fact, "turbulent" is also used figuratively in the same way. (For example, this article, ["Target Hit Some Turbulence This Summer,"](http://www.tulsaworld.com/business/retail/target-hit-some-turbulence-this-summer/article_628e1208-9c5b-5a23-b9f5-fda7e55ea03b.html) talks about how the store's sales have been declining.

Transportation metaphors like these are fairly common. When things go wrong, you can also say you...

- hit a rough patch
- have a bumpy road ahead of you
- have an uphill drive/climb

And of course, when things improve, you have clear skies and smooth sailing!